# Python 3.4 - Putting variables into input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to calculate the total amount based on two answers to inputs.

Example;

```
type1_value=100
type2_value=200

model1_value=2
model2_value=3

typevalue=str(input('please enter the type:  '))
modelvalue=str(input('please enter the model:  '))

total=(typevalue*modelvalue)
```

if customer types type1 for first and model2 for second question how can I have 
300 in total?

thanks

Comment: You can add them?

Comment: It is not possible. I am tempted to answer, but this looks like homework. Are not there any rules against that?

Comment: I think you're looking for this : https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, rather than using variables, you want a dict of values:

```
typevalues = {
    "type1": 100,
    "type2": 200
}

modelvalues = {
    "model1": 2,
    "model2": 3
}

type_ = str(input('please enter the type: '))
model = str(input('please enter the model: '))

total = typevalues[type_] * modelvalues[model]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary:

```
types = {"type1_value": 100, "type2_value": 200}
type=str(input('please enter the type:  '))
typevalue=types[type]
```

Same for the models.

Read more about dictionaries [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, by far, is to use dictionary:

```
type = {} 
type['type1'] = 100
type['type2'] = 200

typevalue = str(input('please enter the type:')) 
val = type[typevalue]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to convert the input to string because it's already a string .
To do what you want you have to check the input and the assign the type or model value.

```
type = input("Enter type: ")
model = input("Enter model: ")
if type == "type1":
     type_value = 100
elif type == "type2":
     type_value = 200
if model == "model1":
     model_value = 2
elif model == "model2":
     model_value = 3
total = type_value*model_value
```